# Arduino Joystick works in serial monitor, not game controller dialog

Tags: arduino, hid, atmega, joystick

I'm trying to create a simple 2-Axis, 2-Button joystick using an off-brand *ATmega32U4* board, which registers as an **Arduino Leonardo**.

I've got it working just fine on the serial monitor in Arduino IDE, and it shows up as a game controller with the correct amount of inputs in "Devices and Printers", but for some reason the serial data isn't transferring to the Game Controller test dialog, so the joystick isn't working outside of the serial monitor.

This is my first project with Arduino, so I'm sure I'm just missing something simple here, but honestly, I'm stumped.

After exhausting all of my Google-fu, and some trial and error, this is the best I could come up with, so I'd appreciate any help I can get in order to get this working properly. I'm using [THIS](https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary/tree/version-2.0) joystick library.

```cpp
// Pin A2 = X Axis
// Pin A3 = Y Axis
// Pin 16 = Button 1
// Pin 10 = Button 2
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------

#include "Joystick.h"

// 2 Buttons, No hats, X and Y axis, no Z axis, Rx, Ry, Rz, Rudder, Throttle, Brake, or Steering
Joystick_ Joystick(JOYSTICK_DEFAULT_REPORT_ID,JOYSTICK_TYPE_JOYSTICK, 2, 0, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {
    ;
    }

    pinMode(A2, INPUT);
    pinMode(A3, INPUT);
    pinMode(16, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(10, INPUT_PULLUP);

    Joystick.begin();
    Joystick.setXAxisRange(-512, 512);
    Joystick.setYAxisRange(-512, 512);
}

void loop() {

    // X-Axis
    int xAxis = analogRead(A2);
    Joystick.setXAxis(xAxis);
    Serial.println(xAxis);

    // Y-Axis
    int yAxis = analogRead(A3);
    Joystick.setYAxis(yAxis);
    Serial.println(yAxis);

    // Button 1
    int button1State = !digitalRead(16);
    if (button1State = 1)
    {         
       Joystick.pressButton(0);
    }

    // Button 2
    int button2State = !digitalRead(10);
    if (button2State = 1)
    {         
       Joystick.pressButton(1);
    }
}
```

I've added delays in my loop, which I thought seemed to fix my issue (and made me notice another issue), but for some reason it only seems to work *part* of the time... Sometimes it works just right, other times the test dialog doesn't notice my inputs, and other times the dialog box just freezes... Here are the changes I've made:

```cpp
// X-Axis
int xAxis = analogRead(A2);
Joystick.setXAxis(xAxis);
Serial.println(xAxis);
delay(50);

// Y-Axis
int yAxis = analogRead(A3);
Joystick.setYAxis(yAxis);
Serial.println(yAxis);
delay(50);

// Button 1
int button1State = !digitalRead(16);
if (button1State == 1)
{         
   Joystick.pressButton(0);
   delay(50);
}


// Button 2
int button2State = !digitalRead(10);
if (button2State == 1)
{         
   Joystick.pressButton(1);
   delay(50);
}
```

Comment: Those delays just make everything horribly unresponsive. You are basically reading an axis/button only every 10 to 5 times a seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying just about everything else I decided to try commenting out all of the serial communication and now it works! I'm not experienced enough with Arduino to know what part of the serial communication I had written was messing things up, but my sketch works just fine without it. (except for one of my buttons, but I think that might just be a faulty pin)

This is what I ended up with in case someone else finds this useful:

```cpp
// Pin A2 = X Axis
// Pin A3 = Y Axis
// Pin 16 = Button 1
// Pin 10 = Button 2
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------

#include "Joystick.h"

Joystick_ Joystick(JOYSTICK_DEFAULT_REPORT_ID,JOYSTICK_TYPE_JOYSTICK, 2, 0, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);

void setup() {    

    pinMode(A2, INPUT);
    pinMode(A3, INPUT);
    pinMode(16, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(10, INPUT_PULLUP);

    Joystick.begin();
}

void loop() {

    // X-Axis
    int xAxis = analogRead(A2);
    Joystick.setXAxis(xAxis);

    // Y-Axis
    int yAxis = analogRead(A3);
    Joystick.setYAxis(yAxis);

    // Button 1
    int button1State = !digitalRead(16);
    if (button1State == 1)
    {         
       Joystick.pressButton(0);
    }
    else
    {  
      Joystick.releaseButton(0);
    }

    // Button 2
    int button2State = !digitalRead(10);
    if (button2State == 1)
    {         
       Joystick.pressButton(1);
    }
    else
    {  
      Joystick.releaseButton(1);
    }

    delay(50);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use == inside the 'if' statement to check for equality, now it is assigning the value 1 regardless of the input.

Comment: I've tried adding that, but as you can see in my edit to the OP, I've got some other issues preventing me from trying out your suggestion.

Comment: Right. It might be too much latency with all delay combined, try adding only single delay(50), as in the library example.

Comment: did you check out the examples in the github repo? I see that they use different delays for joystick functions (cycle/button/analog) [here](https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary/blob/version-2.0/Joystick/examples/JoystickTest/JoystickTest.ino#L22)

Comment: Yeah, I've read through all of them and tried adapting them to my use-case and ended up starting from scratch with the above sketch. I have no idea what my issue is here, it worked just fine for a minute (other than the buttons, but I think your suggestion should fix that), and now it's back to not working anymore... I've even downloaded the joystick testing software the author of the library suggested and it's not picking up any of my inputs at all. This doesn't seem to make sense; I even reverted back to the backup that was working without the buttons, and it's not anymore...

Answer (score 1):

`while (!Serial)` waits for the serial connection to open. When you open the Arduino IDE's serial monitor your code starts to execute. If you don't, the code won't run and no inputs will be sent to the PC.

Remove the

```cpp
while (!Serial) {
;
}
```

it's only intended for debugging, so the program starts when you open the serial monitor and you don't miss any debugging messages at the beginning.

Comment: Would it be advantageous for me to create a serial connection at all, since my joystick seems to be working fine without one?

Comment: No, since you are not doing anything with the serial.